# Codeigniter: Not sure how to make calls to this snippet of code

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, inheritance

I was browsing SO and found this hosted code as a recommended way of cutting down on PHP code.

https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model

So far, from the methods that I have figured out how to use, I love what it does and how simple it makes things.

However, in the following code:

```
/**
 * Get a single record by creating a WHERE clause by passing
 * through a CI AR where() call
 *
 * @param string $key The key to search by 
 * @param string $val The value of that key
 * @return object
 */
public function get_by() {
    $where =& func_get_args();
    $this->_set_where($where);

    $this->_run_before_get();
    $row = $this->db->get($this->_table)
                    ->row();
    $this->_run_after_get($row);
    return $row;
}
```

I'm not exactly sure how to make a call to this function.
The description of what it does is exactly what I want to do.

The @params say it takes in a key and value pair for the WHERE block but I don't see any function inputs in the method signature.

Help, please?

Comment: You want to use the entire class or just that method?

Comment: I'm trying to use the class. He has good instructions to set up so I was able to "install" the class with no problem. I can make function calls to other methods. Just not sure how to go about call this method in particular since I haven't seen any sample code.

Comment: Methods become part of your model, only call these from one of your own methods: `$query= $this->get_by($key,$val);` and then `$query->fied;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I'm noticing with a lot of CI code, it's strange and maintenance un-friendly.

PHP functions can accept *n* or more arguments (where *n* is the number of arguments defined in the signature)

The code makes use of [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) which returns an array of arguments.

The array of arguments is then passed to the `_set_where()` method which passes either one or two items to the `db->where()` method.

A more descriptive method signature would have been

```
public function get_by($key, $val = null)
```

Comment: Got confused by using the term key... if he had said column name I wouldn't have been confused at all.

    { $this->some_model->get_by('some_primarykey_columnid_name','some_value'); } How do you put code brackets in comments?

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, and like Phil mentioned, the `*_by` methods pass the value through to the `db->where` method. This means you can use it in a variety of methods:

```
$row = $this->model->get_by('key', $value);
```

Or using an array for multiple WHERE conditions:

```
$row = $this->model->get_by(array('key' => $value, 'other_key !=' => $value));
```

Or just the string (don't forget to escape your values!):

```
$row = $this->model->get_by('some_column = ' . $this->db->escape($value));
```

Since this question was asked, I've [thoroughly updated the documentation](https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model#codeigniter-base-model) so now it should all be a little clearer. Hope this helps.